# Laravel - How to write this in Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Lets say I have a MessageThread which has many Messages.  And each Message is associated with one User.

How would i get all MessageThread objects containing at least one Message that is associated with a particular User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `whereHas` constraints:

```
$threads = MessageThread::whereHas('messages', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', 1);
    });
})->get();
```